# Wordpress custom text on every post/page

Tags: wordpress

Can someone help me in figuring out how I have added following text automatically on every post and pages :
Share this:
Click to share on LinkedIn 
Like this:

I remember modifying some php file long time ago , but can't remember which.
I have tried reinstalling the wordpress but for no avail, the text remains..
I want to remove this text from appearing automatically now from my every post and pages..

Appreciate your help.

Link to my site where you can see this problem : https://iamtechtips.com/about-me/